# Separable morphism of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, schemes, resolution-of-singularities

A proof from Janos Kollar's Lectures on Resolution of Singularities Kollar (p 37) works as follows:

> **Theorem 1.58** (M. Noether, 1871). Let $k$ be an algebraically closed
>   field and $C \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ an irreducible plane curve. Then the algorithm (1.57)
>   eventually stops with a curve $C_m \subset \mathbb{P}^2$, which has only ordinary multiple
>   points (1.54).
>
> We give two proofs. The first one assumes that we already know embedded
>   resolution as in (1.52). The second, following Noether’s original
>   approach, gives another proof of embedded resolution.
>
> *Proof using resolution.* Pick any point $p \in C \subset \mathbb{P}^2$, and let $\pi : C \to \mathbb{P}^1$ be
>   the projection from $p$. In characteristic zero or if the characteristic does not divide $\operatorname{deg} C − \operatorname{mult}_p C$, the projection $\pi$ is separable.

(This fact we can look up on page 15 but also simply assumed as black box: i.e. from now we assume that $\pi$ is separable: field extension $K(C)/K(\overline{\pi(C)}$ is separable.)

Now the part I not understand:

> *Thus we can take two general lines through $p$ such that they are not contained in the tangent cone of $C$ at $p$ and they have only transverse intersections with $C$
>   at other points.* [...]

**Question:** Why separability of $\pi$ is neccessary to be able to choose these two lines with described properties and what fails if $\pi$ would be not separable?

We know that seprableness of $\pi$ implies that a general fiber of $\pi$ has $\operatorname{deg} \pi$ points. Possibly, if $\operatorname{deg} \pi >1$ this might be give rise for two "candidates" for the two lines trough $p$ with desired properties, but it can also happen that $\operatorname{deg} \pi =1$ & $\pi$ separable. Thus I unfortunately not see the crucialness of separateness of $\pi$ for the justification of the existence of the the lines.

#Edit: As GTA pointed out at first glance it's not clear where $p$ is mapped by the considered projection. On page 12 I found Kollar's explanation on this issue:

> (2)"Assume that $p \in C \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ is a singular point, where $m$ smooth
>   branches of the curve pass through with different tangent directions. Projecting
>   $C$ from $p$ separates these tangent directions, and the singular point
>   $p$ is replaced by $m$ points with only one local branch through each of them."

Comment: Where does p go through this projection from p map?

Comment: @GTA:on page 12 Kollar says: ..."Assume that $p \in C \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ is a singular point, where $m$ smooth
branches of the curve pass through with different tangent directions. Projecting
$C$ from $p$ separates these tangent directions, and the singular point
$p$ is replaced by $m$ points with only one local branch through each of them." I think this is what he also implicitly means in the projection map from above.

Comment: You are right, that's an important point. I will add it in the question.

Comment: Separability is needed for the intersections of the line with $C$ to be transverse. A general fibre of the projection will consist of distinct reduced points iff the map is separable.

Comment: @ulrich: Yes, I think I understand. That's a consequence of Bézout's theorem, right? The general fiber coinsides with intersection of a line through $p$ with $C$. By Bezout & counting at every point of the intersection with such general line must be transversal. And separable implies that we have enough such lines. Thank you!